# VS 2013 xaml editor preview error

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I recently installed VS 2013 professional update 4 on Windows 8.1. And i create a sample project by VS windows phone template. When I open up project i get this error message given below.

[image]

**I can't fix this problem by renewing developer licence.**

> System.Exception Package failed updates, dependency or conflict validation.
>
> Windows cannot install package App.a9ddd834a.a19c4.a43a9.a9a4f.a820be57d3620 because this package depends on another package that could not be found. This package requires minimum version 0.0.0.0 of framework Microsoft.VCLibs.120.00.Debug published by any publisher to install. Provide the framework along with this package

Comment: try to make re-install for Windows Phone SDK and install all update that related with last SDK version,also you should make update your visual studio .

Comment: already done 2 or 3 time...no change